# Notify Wordpress Site I Have Linked To Them

Tags: php, comments, pingbacks

I have noticed that when a Wordpress site puts a link to my site in a post it shows their website in the comments section of my site.

I'm wonder how could I make my PHP application do this? I mean when I link to a Wordpress site in my application it will show up in the comments section on the site I linked to automatically. I've tried to search on Google how to do this but I can't find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term you need to search for is "Pingbacks" (and maybe "Trackbacks", but the former is better as it is less vulnerable to spam abuse).

It is an XML-RPC request. You can find [the specification here](http://www.hixie.ch/specs/pingback/pingback).

Looking at github there seem to be some bare metal PHP implementations, but as I haven't used any of them I am not going to link to them directly, but you can easily find them via Google.

Also be aware that you can only notify a site. If it cares about the notification as well as if and how the link is display is of course out of your control.